# Zapier inputFields duplication

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I am building a Zapier application using the CLI tool. The issue i'm having right now is I have duplicate input fields showing up for only some fields. The fields that are duplicated I confirmed are under the `operation.inputFields` in my gift creates file.  ["Gift Amount" and "Amount". It seems like "Gift Amount" is what I would want since it is pulling in the right value from the response.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wog8T.png). Here is what I have in code inside the Gift creates file -> [I tried adding the attribute "Label" to see maybe it would help but issue still was there.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3dA1.png) . Here is also what the api will return as well -> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAYdO.png)

I tried removing the inputFields under the `operation.InputFields` but the duplicated fields are still showing up. I also tried removing the `noun` attribute since I see "Gift" is tagged infront of all the duplicated fields. ex. Gift Amount(api return just "amount", Gift Gift Project Id(api returns just "Gift Project Id) etc."

Any ideas on where I should look at? I appreciate the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I found the fix for this issue. I resolved this by changing my sample object to match what my api is returning. I believe Zapier looks at the sample object on the trigger to basically define the structure. I originally had my sample object like so -> `sample: { id: 1, transactionSource: "string", transactionId: 1,..` what I needed was to append the gift key to the sample object (just like how my api returns -> `sample: { gift: { id: 1, transactionSource: "string", transactionId: 1,...` this resolved the duplicated input fields.